# Ruby Brainfuck interpreter

Tags: ruby, interpreter, brainfuck

I recently wrote a simple Brainfuck interpreter in Ruby:

```
require "io/console"

$VALID = "+-<>.,"

def parse(code, level=0)
    ast = []
    while !code.empty? do
        c = code.shift
        if c == "]" then
            if level == 0 then
                throw Exception.new "Unmatched brackets"
            else
                return ast
            end
        end
        if c == "[" then
            ast.push parse(code, level+1)
        elsif $VALID.include? c then
            ast.push c
        end
    end
    if level != 0 then
        throw Exception.new "Unmatched brackets"
    end
    ast
end

class BF
    def initialize
        @tape = Array.new 3e4, 0
        @ptr = 3e4.to_i / 2
    end

    def run(ast)
        ast.each {|e|
            if e.kind_of? Array then
                while @tape[@ptr] != 0 do
                    self.run e
                end
            else
                case e
                when "+"
                    @tape[@ptr] += 1
                when "-"
                    @tape[@ptr] -= 1
                when ">"
                    @ptr += 1
                when "<"
                    @ptr -= 1
                when "."
                    STDOUT.write @tape[@ptr].chr
                when ","
                    @tape[@ptr] = STDIN.getch.ord
                end
                @tape[@ptr] &= 0xFF
            end
        }
    end
end

if ARGV[0] == nil then
    puts "Simple BrainFuck interpreter"
    puts "Usage: #{$0} <file>"
    exit 1
end
bf = BF.new
bf.run parse(File.read(ARGV[0]).chars)
```

I am pretty bad at Ruby, can someone review this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Global variables should always be avoided, so instead of `$VALID` it should simply be `VALID`. The entire Ruby ecosystem does not need access to that variable and it might overwrite some important variable somewhere.

Instead of `Exception` you should be using `StandardError`. Rubyists do not rescue Exceptions ever really because it catches every single possible exception or error, so if someone (including you) wants to rescue from `parse`, it will be confusing and non idiomatic. Exception is the top level class for all errors, including syntax errors, interruption errors, and memory errors. I would recommend either doing the simple `fail "Error"`, or take a more object oriented approach (which will improve potential rescues) and create a new error object, perhaps `UnmatchedBracketsError` which inherits StandardError. This also means that when you decide to change the message, you only need to change it in the `UnmatchedBracketsError` class rather than in both of the identical `throw` calls.

I may be misunderstanding the scoping decisions taken here but it seems like `parse` should be a method in the BF class. It can be "static" by doing `def self.parse`, but it just seems weird to have it in the main namespace. Moving that would also mean it would make sense to move `VALID` out of the main namespace and into `BF`.

`Array#<<` is faster than `Array#push` so I recommend using that.

Now for the stylistic things.

Typically, multiline blocks are defined using `do end` syntax rather than `{}`. So

```
ast.each {|e|
    ...
}
```

becomes

```
ast.each do |e|
    ...
end
```

Every instance of `then` in your code is unnecessary.

For that `ARGV[0] == nil` call, firstly it can be optimized to `ARGV[0].nil?`. After that, it might be better to use the boolean-y value of `ARGV[0]`. So `if ARGV[0] == nil` -> `if ARGV[0].nil?` -> `unless ARGV[0]`.

```
if level != 0 then
    throw Exception.new "Unmatched brackets"
end
```

can be shortened to `throw Exception.new("Unmatched brackets") if level != 0`.

Both of your `while` loops are using negated conditionals, which means they can be idiomatically changed to `until` loops. `while !empty?` can become `until empty?` and `while a != 0` can become `until a == 0`.

Lastly, I'm pretty sure `self` can be omitted in the `run` call.